# How to implement chained method calls like jQuery?

Tags: javascript, object

So I am (still) completely in love with the almighty jQuery, and I have my own growing library of utilities that I want to codify in a java-script object. And I would like to keep syntax similar to that of jquery for the sake of simplicity for my other front end devs. So I want something like this:

```
 foo(argument).method(argument);
```

I have been trying something like this:

```
var foo = function(str){
    this.str = str;
}

foo.prototype = {
    alertTest  :  function(additional){
         alert(this.str + ' ' + additional);
    }
}
```

So that foo('hello').alertTest('world); with alert 'hello world'

I know this is possible, but I am not an OO guy and need help getting this simple thing right. Please help. I also intend on having many foo().bar(); type functions, like foo().somethingelse(); and foo().anotherthing(); . I have made several attempts, but am struggling hard here. Also there must be an awesome tight way of doing it.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
new foo('hello').alertTest('world');
```

or if you don't like the `new`:

```
var bar = function bar(str) {
    this.str = str;    
};

bar.prototype = {
    alertTest :  function(additional){
        alert(this.str + ' ' + additional);
        return this;
    }
};

function foo(str) {
    return new bar(str);
}

foo('hello').alertTest('world');
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vh9g6/8/).

Comment: But I don't want to write 'new' I want the object to already exist.

Comment: @Fresheyeball, great, see my updated answer. The `foo` method must return an object if you want to continue chaining method calls. So the  `alertTest` function that you are invoking must be defined on the object that the `foo` function returns.

Comment: To improve a little bit: adding `return this;` after the `alert(this.str)` line will allow you to do lots of chaining: `foo().alert().asdf()` :)

Comment: @Michael Jasper, excellent remark. I have updated my post to take it into account.

Answer (score 2):

I did something like this a while ago and it was a ton of fun to create!

If i remember correctly, To be able to use dot-operators, I had to return the object as part of the original function call. This way I could chain lots of stuff together like `$(id).value('asdf').color('#ff0000')`

```
function $(id){
    this.e = document.getelementbyid(id)
    me = this
    this.val = function (newval) {
        this.e.value = newval;
        return me;  // <- Important
    };
    return this;  //  <- Important
}

$("textbox1").val("New Value")    // changes textbox1's value to "New Value"
```

If it helps for reference: http://www.mikedoesweb.com/vis/

Answer (score 1):

Something I did really quick but you can relate to the essence of what we are trying to achieve here -

```
function ChainingObj() {
  if (!(this instanceof ChainingObj)) {
    return new ChainingObj();
  }
}

ChainingObj.prototype.first = function() {
  console.log("foo");
  return this; //important to return this.
}


ChainingObj.prototype.second = function() {
  console.log("bar");
  return this;
}

var a = ChainingObj().first().second();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite late to answer this question and also jquery is quite deprecated. But still people get asked this question quite frequently.

I would implement like below without using prototype -

```js
const wrapper = (person) => ({
    sayGoodMorning:() => {
        console.log("Good Morning, "+person.name)
        return wrapper(person);
    },
    showAlert:() => {
       alert("Hey I am alert");
       return wrapper(person);
    },
    sayGoodEvening:() => {
        console.log("Good Evening, " + person.name)
        return wrapper(person);
    },
    sayGoodNight:() => {
        console.log("Good Night, " + person.name)
        return wrapper(person);
    },
  });
  const person = {name:"StackOverflow"};
  const $ = (obj) => wrapper(obj);
  const $example = $(person);
  
  $example
    .showAlert()
    .sayGoodMorning()
    .sayGoodEvening()
    .sayGoodNight();
```