# javascript OOP syntax, and object that is both a var and a function

Tags: javascript, oop

This is related to a question I asked previously here: [How to implement chained method calls like jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354760/how-to-implement-chained-method-calls-like-jquery)

I have been using the method from the check answer from some time there, and it works well. But I would like to alter the syntax for my toolkit even further.

1. `foo(firstarg).bar(secondarg); // should function as the question above.`
2. `foo(onlyarg).bar // a function with one argument`
3. `foo.bar(onlyarg); // should also work, when a first argument is not appropriate.`
4. `foo.bar; // a function without an argument, or returns a static value.`

I would like all 4 syntaxs to work off the same foo object, but lack the OOP understanding to do so. I have tried a few things, and so far I can get 1 & 2 to work, and 3 & 4 to work, but not to all work together. It also would be nice if chaining remained an option by having each function return the root object.

Edit: I clearly need to be more specific, here is what I have now:

```
 var main = function(obj){ this.obj = obj; };
 var tool = function(obj){ return new main(obj); };
 main.prototype = {
      alertThisPlus : function(plus){
           alert(this.obj + ' ' + plus);    
      },
      alertJustThis : function(){
           return alert(this.obj);
      }
 };
```

usage

```
 tool('hello').alertThisPlus('world'); // returns alert('hello world')
 tool().alertJustThis('hello world');  // returns alert('hello world');
```

what I would like is to do this:

```
 tool('hello').alertThisPlus('world'); // returns alert('hello world') no change
 tool.alertJustThis('hello world');  // returns alert('hello world') does not work
```

Comment: This really isn't OOP... but mute point. 3 and 4 are incompatable unless `bar` is a function. The best you can do to make them compatable is to call `bar` with no arguments. Likewise with 1 and 2.

Comment: right. I have 1&2 working already, and I have 3&4 working already. Its getting all working at once. I know its possible because of jquery: both $(arg).foo works, as well as $.browser for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions are just objects so you can add functions to 'tool'.  You can do this manually:

```
tool.foobar = function() {};
```

Or if your classes are structured suitably you could use a mix-in approach.  Something like this:

```
function Tool(prefix) {
  this.prefix = prefix;
}

Tool.prototype.alertThisPlus = function(suffix) {
  alert((typeof this.prefix != 'undefined' ? this.prefix + ' ' : '') + suffix);
};

Tool.prototype.alertJustThis = function(msg) {
  alert(msg);
};

function tool(prefix) {
  return new Tool(prefix);
}

// Mix-in the methods from a static instance of Tool onto the 'tool' function.
// This makes both tool.alertThisPlus() and tool.alertJustThis() available,
// both will be called in the context of 'staticTool'.
(function() {
  var staticTool = new Tool();
  for (var o in staticTool) {
    if (typeof staticTool[o] == 'function') {
      tool[o] = staticTool[o].bind(staticTool);
    }
  }
})();

tool('hello').alertThisPlus('world'); // returns alert('hello world')
tool().alertJustThis('hello world');  // returns alert('hello world')
tool.alertJustThis('hello world');    // returns alert('hello world')
```

Comment: Note, `Function.bind()` isn't supported by all browsers yet so you may need to use a closure or write your own bind function.

Comment: I understand everything but this part: (function() {
  var staticTool = new Tool();
  for (var o in staticTool) {
    if (typeof staticTool[o] == 'function') {
      tool[o] = staticTool[o].bind(staticTool);
    }
  }
})();

Comment: Can you explain what is going on there more?

Comment: It creates a static instance of `Tool` and then copies each of the methods onto the `tool` function.  If you did: `tool[o] = staticTool[o]` they would be called in the global context, by using bind you are binding the scope to `staticTool`.  It's equivalent to: `tool[o] = function() { staticTool[o].apply(staticTool, arguments); }`

Comment: I am having a problem with this code, and am sure its a lacking in my understanding. The line here `tool[o] = staticTool[o].bind(staticTool);` throws an error in ie 7 and 8. "Object doesn't support this property or method" any idea why? I don't undertand what .bind really does.

Comment: See my first comment.  `Function.bind()` isn't supported in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of that would allow you to execute a function without parenthesis is if you are a) passing it as a callback param, or b) having it self execute.

```
var foo = (function() {
  alert('foo called');
})();
```

Taking that a step further, lets say you've use some closures to return values.

```
var foo = (function() {
  return {
    bar: "arf arf said the dog"
  }
})();
```

Now you can use:

```
foo.bar;
```